# postgresql: permission denied for sequence <table>_i_seq

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a schema of a table in PostgreSQL that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  data.pmacct (

    i                       BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
```

And there are users:

- **A**: superuser privileges
- **B**: read/write privileges
- **C**: read privileges

And I have made the following modifications in regards to the privileges (as user **A**)

```
CREATE SCHEMA data ;
ALTER DATABASE ip_spotlight SET search_path TO data ;
REVOKE EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA data FROM PUBLIC ;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA data GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO C ;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA data GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO B ;
```

as user `postgres`

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA data TO netops ;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA data TO netopsapp ;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA data TO C ;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA data TO C ;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA data TO C ;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA data TO B ;
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA data TO B ;
GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA data TO B ;
```

But I am getting the following error message as user **B**

> ERROR:  permission denied for sequence pmacct_i_seq

Could you please enlighten me what I have done wrong and user **B** is not able to do an `INSERT` statement into the `data.pmacct` table ?

Comment: You should have an error, but not that one. When is `B` granted USAGE to the `data` schema?

Comment: @DanielVérité am not sure if i understand the question: doesn't `ALL` include `USAGE` ?

Comment: What `ALL` means depends on the `ON` clause. In the case of the **schema itself** , there's no `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA data to B` in the commands mentioned above.

Comment: Could you please show the output of `\dp pmacct_i_seq` (run in `psql`)?

Answer (score 4):

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCE some_table_name_i_seq TO some_user;
```

In this case:

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCE pmacct_i_seq TO B;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres 15+ it is much easier to grant useful permissions while setting up your database by using predefined roles.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html

```sql
    GRANT pg_read_all_data TO USER;  
    -- Grants USAGE (which includes SELECT) on all schemas. 
    -- Grants SELECT on all tables, views, and sequences.
    
    GRANT pg_write_all_data TO USER;
    -- Grants USAGE on all schemas. 
    -- Grants INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on all tables, views, and sequences.
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO B;
```

`pmacct_i_seq` is a sequence that backs the `BIGSERIAL` column `i`. Since user B can modify the table, it needs the privilege to access the sequence.

Answer (score -2):

Try to make changes  on all tables
Answer from Alex Soto

---

Since you're changing the ownership for all tables, you likely want views and sequences too.  Here's what I did:

Tables:

```
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';" YOUR_DB` ; do  psql -c "alter table \"$tbl\" owner to NEW_OWNER" YOUR_DB ; done
```

Sequences:

```
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select sequence_name from information_schema.sequences where sequence_schema = 'public';" YOUR_DB` ; do  psql -c "alter table \"$tbl\" owner to NEW_OWNER" YOUR_DB ; done
```

Views:

```
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select table_name from information_schema.views where table_schema = 'public';" YOUR_DB` ; do  psql -c "alter table \"$tbl\" owner to NEW_OWNER" YOUR_DB ; done
```

You could probably [DRY][1] that up a bit since the alter statements are identical for all three.